# How to setup a policy for Amazon S3 bucket to be accessible only to an IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, policy

I have a bunch of files that I would like to put on S3 such that access to them is restricted only to a particular IAM user. I've tried associating a policy with the user, and with the bucket, and am trying to access a file in the bucket using s3-cmd. However, I keep getting the access denied xml in the response (403 forbidden). My policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Sid": "<a statementID>",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-account-num>:user/<username>"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>"
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Only if I set the Principal to "AWS": "*", am I able to download the resource through the REST calls.

The user in question has the "Power User" policy attached to it:

```
{
  "Statement": [
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "*"
   }
 ]
```

}

How do I use an S3 bucket for private-only access? Please help.

Comment: Can you post a full solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was not with the policy, but the machine it was accessed from. I was trying to do a retrieve operation for an S3 resource from an EC2 instance. Today I found out that one can make every EC2 instance "assume" an IAM Role. When the instance does that, it inherits the permissions specified for that role. So just creating a role with the following policy:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": "s3:*",
     "Resource": "*"
    }
   ]
}
```

and making the EC2 instance assume this role allows it to communicate with the S3 buckets.

Comment: Except your EC2 instance can access every S3 bucket and perform every action on every bucket. If your EC2 instance is compromised, any attacker can delete all of your buckets. You should see these articles:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html